# Azure B2C federated sign out is not complete (identity token is not passed to third party end session endpoint)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have application which uses Azure B2C as IDP. Azure B2C provides a possible to use local account or federation via OpenIdConnect to third party IDP (Identity Server). I'm using custom policies in B2C. Login works fine but I have issues with sign out. Sign out from federated identity provider is executed but identity token of third party IDP is not passed to the end session endpoint and sign out is not properly executed.

Sign out requests:

1. GET https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44317%2Fsignout-callback-oidc&id_token_hint=xxxxx
2. GET https://thirdpartyidp.com/idp/connect/endsession <- id_token_hint querystring parameter is missing from here
3. GET https://thirdpartyidp.com/idp/logout?id=xxxxx
4. GET https://localhost:44317/signout-callback-oidc?state=xxxxx

I have tested this also with out of box user flow but same problem occurs.

I'm using this technical profile configuration:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>thirdpartyidp</Domain>
    <DisplayName>thirdpartyidp</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="thirdpartyidp-OAUTH">
        <DisplayName>thirdpartyidp</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="ProviderName">thirdpartyidp</Item>
          <Item Key="METADATA">https://thirdpartyidp.com/idp/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
          <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://thirdpartyidp.com</Item>
          <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">app</Item>
          <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
          <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
          <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
          <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
          <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
          <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
          <Item Key="client_id">app</Item>
          <Item Key="SingleLogoutEnabled">true</Item>        
        </Metadata>
        <CryptographicKeys>
          <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_thirdpartyidp" />
        </CryptographicKeys>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
          <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
          <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
      </TechnicalProfile>   
    </TechnicalProfiles>
  </ClaimsProvider>
```

I found two-three year old articles that Azure AD B2C does not support signing you out from the external identity provider. According this pretty new article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#sign-out) it should be possible if I understood correctly. Azure B2C definitely attempts federated sign out but it's not complete.

Do I have some kind of custom policy configuration problem or what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#secure-your-logout-redirect) your relying party to send the Id token during signout.

```xml
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" EnforceIdTokenHintOnLogout="true"/>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from MS support that passing identity token to third party IDP end session endpoint is not currently supported.

Comment: Hi, I too have this problem. I am interested to know how did you workaround this problem. Please let me know.